# I want to take 4 strings as an input and display into another array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to take 5 strings as an input and display into another array using 2-d arrays and pointer notation. However, I am stuck up.

I am confused with the array and pointer notation in the function call and definition and how is a 2d array pointer is used when to access a specific action. Each string has max length 20 and I want 5 such strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void *func(char (*str1)[20]);
void *func1(char (*str1)[20]);

int
main(void)
{
    char (*a)[20];

    func1(a);
    printf("The string you just entered is:\n");
    func(a);
}

void *
func(char (*str1)[20])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    char (*str2)[20];

    while (j < 5) {
        while (*str1[i] != '\0') {
            *str2[i] = *str1[i];
            i++;
        }
        puts(str2[j]);
        j++;
    }
}

void *
func1(char (*str1)[20])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *res;

    while (j < 5) {
        res = fgets(str1[j], 20, stdin);

        if (res) {
            while (*str1[i] != '\n' && *str1[i] != '\0')
            {
                i++;
            }

            if (*str1[i] == '\n') {
                *str1[i] = '\0';
            }
            else {
                while (getchar() != '\n') {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: in main *a* is not initialized, you will have undefined behavior in *func1* using it. In *func* at line `*str2[i]=*str1[i];` *str2* is not initialized, behavior is undefined. WHy declaring functions return `void *` if you do not `return` something ? use `void` rather than `void *`

Comment: If you compile with `-Wall -O2` [which you should _always_ do], a number of lines are flagged with warnings [about _uninitialized_ variables, etc.].

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code.

> These require `void*` return:
>
> ```
> void *func(char (*str1)[20]);  
> void *func1(char (*str1)[20]);
> ```

---

> This is pointer is uninitialized, you then pass it to the functions, this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), you'll need to allocate memory for them.
>
> ```
> char (*a)[20];
> ```

If you want to maintain the `(*a)[20]` notation you'll still need to initialize it, allocating enough memory to hold the strings you are assigning.

So its 5 lines of 20 characters each, so its 20 * 5 characters, [**it would look something like this**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/CrowdedVigorousCopycat), with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5      //macros to hold the dimensions
#define LENGTH 20

void* func(char (*str1)[LENGTH]); //you can return str2
void func1(char (*str1)[LENGTH]); //no return needed here

int main(void)
{
    char (*a)[LENGTH];
    char (*b)[LENGTH];  //to hold str2, otherwise it's lost at function return

    if(!(a = malloc(N * LENGTH))) { // allocationg necessary memory, char has the size of 1 byte
       perror("No memory!");
    }

    func1(a);   
    b = func(a); //assigning str2 to b

    puts("The strings you just entered are:"); //printing str2's now assingned to b
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        puts(b[i]);
    }
}

void* func(char (*str1)[LENGTH])
{
    char(*str2)[LENGTH];
    str2 = malloc(N * LENGTH); //also needs memory allocation

    for (int i = 0, j; i < N; i++) //declaring i and j inside the scope of for
    {
        for (j = 0; j < LENGTH && str1[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            str2[i][j] = str1[i][j]; //copying char by char, note thar you can use strcpy or similar to copy the str1 to str2
        }
        str2[i][j] = '\0'; //null terminate str2
    }
    return str2; //returning str2
}

void func1(char (*str1)[LENGTH])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < N && printf("Enter string %d: ", i + 1) && fgets(str1[i], LENGTH, stdin)) //getting all the strings
    {
        str1[i][strcspn(str1[i], "\n")] = '\0'; // replace \n
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that some of the logic in your functions is faulty and will cause undefined behaviour, I changed it maintaining the char by char copy, though you could use library functions such as `strcpy` to copy the strings.

Personally I would use double pointer notation, it still allows you to access the strings as if they were in a classic 2D array, i.e. using `str[i][j]` notation.

[**Here is a possible implementation**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/TruthfulWhichCompilerbug) using only pointers with some comments to clarify:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5
#define LENGTH 20

void func(char **str1);
void func1(char **str1, char **str2);

int main() {

    char **a, **b; //double pointers emulate 2D array

    if (!((a = malloc(N * sizeof(*a))) && (b = malloc(N * sizeof(*b))))) { //allocate memory for lines
        perror("Memory allocation failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { //allocate memory for columns
        if (!((a[i] = malloc(LENGTH)) && (b[i] = malloc(LENGTH)))) {
            perror("Memory allocation failed!");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    func1(a, b);
    printf("The strings you just entered are:\n");
    func(b);
}

void func(char **str2) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { //print all the arrays
        puts(str2[i]);
    }
}

void func1(char **str1, char **str2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter string %d: ", i + 1);
        if (fgets(str1[i], LENGTH, stdin)) { //get strings
            str1[i][strcspn(str1[i], "\n")] = '\0'; //remove \n from string
            strcpy(str2[i], str1[i]); //copy strings to second array
        }
    }
}
```

I used mainly your variable and function names, but note that these should be more meaningful.

Comment: The pointer (*a)[20] is meant to be an input of 5 lines from the user. Could you just specify how to initialize such a 2d array?

Comment: @AdityaSarin, Yes I can, I added it to the answer, let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: Thankyou so much @anataciu